# Pandas : Get binary OR/AND for all the columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

Say I have a dataframe. (Original dataframe has 91 columns 1000 rows)

```
       0      1     2      3
0  False  False   False    True
1   True  False   False   False
2   True  False   False   False
3  False  False    True   False
4  False   True    True   False
5  False  False   False   False 
6   True   True    True    True
```

I need to get the `AND/OR` values for all the columns in my dataframe. So the resultant `OR, AND` values would be.

```
      OR     AND
0    True   False
1    True   False
2    True   False
3    True   False
4    True   False
5    False  False
6    True    True
```

I can do this by looping over all my columns and calculate the boolean for each column but I was looking for a more dataframe level approach without actually going through the columns.

Comment: If you don't care about column names you could do `df.agg(['any', 'all'], axis=1)`, the column names would be `any`, `and`.

Comment: Just for fun: `df.agg(['prod', 'sum'], axis=1).astype(bool)` also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `any` and `all`.

```py
df = df.assign(OR=df.any(axis=1), AND=df.all(axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ll wait for some more answers

Comment: I would recommend this, as it is more clear and concise, and I would prioritize this over efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

You can sum along the columns and then the `OR` is indicated by `sum > 0`, and `AND` is indicated by `sum == len(df.columns)`:

```py
total = df.sum(axis=1)
res = pd.DataFrame({"OR": total > 0, "AND": total == len(df.columns)})
```

If you have many columns this is more efficient as it only iterates over the entire matrix once (in the worst case, depending on the input distribution and implementation of any/all iterating twice can be faster).